# Recursive definition of function choose k xs

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem found in "Introduction to functional programming" First edition Bird-Wadler.

> 5 .6.2 The function choose k xs returns a list of all subsequences of xs whose
>   length is exactly k. For example:
>   ? choose 3 "list"
>   ["ist" , "lst" , "lit" , "lis"]
>   Give a recursive definition of choose. Show that if xs has length n then
>   choose k xs has length nk

I only could come up with a non-recursive solution based on a function that returns the list of subsets of an array:

```
subs :: [a] -> [[a]]
subs [] = [[]]
subs (x:xs) = subs xs ++ map (x:) (subs xs)

choose :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
choose x = filter ((== x) . length) . subs
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: But here you calll `subs` in terms of `subs`, so that *is* a recursive function.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson my question is the recursive solution of the problem

Comment: @acontell: and what is not recursive about your solution? `subs` is a recursive function, and `filter` is recursive as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, indeed. But the length of my recursive function is 2 to the power of n. However, the exercise states that choose n xs has length nk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking:

> What is a lone, recursive function solution to this problem?

These problems usually can be solved if you mentally walk through the base and recursive cases carefully.  For example:

Choose is a function from ints and list of values to a list of lists of values:

```
choose :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

If the result is supposed to be 0 length then there is exactly one sublist of said length:

```
choose 0 _ = [ [] ]
```

If the result is non-zero but we have no more characters with which to make a sublist then there are no solutions:

```
choose _ [] = []
```

Otherwise we can take the first character and append that to all solutions of length one shorter:

```
choose n (x : xs) =
    map (x :) (choose (n - 1) xs)
```

Or we discard this character (ex, drop 'l' and get the result "ist") and look for a solution with the substring:

```
      ++ choose n xs
```